# Scanf through pipe lock

Tags: c

I have an exercise where I need to interact with a C program through pipe.

I have the following source, which I can't modify.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int number;
    int answer;

    number = rand() % 100;
    printf("Print the double of the number %d\n", number);
    scanf("%d", &answer);
    if(number * 2 == answer)
        printf("Success\n");
    else
        printf("Error\n");
}
```

I tried to interact with this program with this code

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
        int STDIN_PIPE[2];
        int STDOUT_PIPE[2];

        pipe(STDIN_PIPE);
        pipe(STDOUT_PIPE);
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0)
        {
                char *path = "/path/to/binary";
                char *args[2];
                args[0] = path;
                args[1] = NULL;
                close(STDIN_PIPE[1]);
                close(STDOUT_PIPE[0]);
                dup2(STDIN_PIPE[0], STDIN_FILENO);
                dup2(STDOUT_PIPE[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                execve(path, args, env);
        }
        else
        {
                char buf[128];
                close(STDIN_PIPE[0]);                                                                                                   
                close(STDOUT_PIPE[1]);                                                                                                  
                while(read(STDOUT_PIPE[0], buf, 1))                                                                                         
                    write(1, buf, 1);                                                                                           
        }                                                                                                               
}
```

But when I run it, it falls in an infinite loop without printing nothing.

Comment: Your program must read the first pipe to get the question from the other program and the write the correct answer to the other pipe, and the read again the first pipe to get success or failure from the other program.

Comment: Yeah i know, but for know i can't even read single charactere.

Comment: You should add some checking to be sure the pipes are created correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed a number of issues in your code, added a lot of error checks and completed it so that the end goal is reached.

In the child process, `srand()` must be called to initialize the random number generator or you always get the same value.

The in the child process, you must `flush(stdout)` after printing the question so that it is really written to the pipe.

And finally, `scanf()` return value must be checked.

In the main process, I added a lot of error checks. And I write a `readLine` function to - guess what - read a line from the pipe. A line is terminated by the end-of-line character `\n`.

There is still room for some enhancements...

I tested my code using Visual Studio Code configured for gcc and running under Ubuntu 20.04.

Here is the child process source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int number;
    int answer;
    time_t t;

    srand((unsigned)time(&t));
    number = rand() % 100;
    printf("Print the double of the number %d\n", number);
    fflush(stdout);
    int n = scanf("%d", &answer);
    if (n != 1) {
        printf("Invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if ((number * 2) == answer) {
        printf("Success\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Error %d is not 2 * %d\n", answer, number);
    return 1;
}
```

And here is the main process source:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int readLine(int fd, char *buf, int bufSize);

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
        int STDIN_PIPE[2];
        int STDOUT_PIPE[2];

        if (pipe(STDIN_PIPE))
        {
                perror("pipe(STDIN_PIPE)");
                return 1;
        }
        if (pipe(STDOUT_PIPE)) {
                perror("pipe(STDOUT_PIPE)");
                return 1;
        }
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
                char *path = "../Child/Child"; // Path to child process, adapt to your environment
                char *args[2];
                args[0] = path;
                args[1] = NULL;
                if (dup2(STDIN_PIPE[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1) {
                        perror("dup2(STDIN) failed");
                        return 1;
                }
                if (dup2(STDOUT_PIPE[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) {
                        perror("dup2(STDIN) failed");
                        return 1;
                }
                // Close all pipe ends
                close(STDIN_PIPE[0]);    // Close read end of STDIN_PIPE
                close(STDIN_PIPE[1]);    // Write end of STDIN_PIPE
                close(STDOUT_PIPE[0]);   // Read end of STDOUT_PIPE
                close(STDOUT_PIPE[1]);   // Close write end of STDOUT_PIPE

                if (execve(path, args, env) == -1) {
                        perror("execve failed");
                        return 1;
                }
        }
        else
        {
                char buf[128];
                int bufSize = sizeof(buf) / sizeof(buf[0]);
                int i;

                // Read the question asked by child process
                if (readLine(STDOUT_PIPE[0], buf, bufSize) < 0) {
                        printf("readLine failed.\n");
                        return 1;
                }

                // We receive something like "Print the double of the number 83"
                printf("Child process question is \"%s\".\n", buf);

                // Extract the number at end of string
                i = strlen(buf) - 1;
                while ((i >= 0) && isdigit(buf[i]))
                        i--;
                int value = atoi(buf + i + 1);

                // Write our answer to write end of STDIN_PIPE
                char answer[128];
                int answerSize = sizeof(answer) / sizeof(answer[0]);
                int answerLen = snprintf(answer, answerSize, "%d\n", value * 2);

                printf("Our answer is \"%d\".\n", value * 2);

                if (write(STDIN_PIPE[1], answer, answerLen) != answerLen) {
                        printf("write failed.\n");
                        return 1;
                }

                // Read the response (success or failure) sent by child process
                if (readLine(STDOUT_PIPE[0], buf, bufSize) < 0) {
                        printf("readLine failed.\n");
                        return 1;
                }

                if (strcasecmp(buf, "Success") == 0)
                        printf("Child process returned success.\n");
                else
                        printf("Child process returned failure.\n");

                // Close all pipe ends
                close(STDIN_PIPE[0]);    // Close read end of STDIN_PIPE
                close(STDIN_PIPE[1]);    // Write end of STDIN_PIPE
                close(STDOUT_PIPE[0]);   // Read end of STDOUT_PIPE
                close(STDOUT_PIPE[1]);   // Close write end of STDOUT_PIPE
        }

        return 0;
}

// Read a line from file descriptor
// A line is any characters until \n is received or EOF
// \n is not kept
// Return the number of characters read or <0 if error:
//    -1 => Input buffer overflow
//    -2 => read() failed and errno has the error 
int readLine(int fd, char *buf, int bufSize)
{
        int i = 0;
        while (1)
        {
                // Check if enough room in the buffer
                if (i >= bufSize) {
                        printf("Input buffer overflow\n");
                        return -1;
                }
                // Read one character from the pipe
                ssize_t n = read(fd, buf + i, 1);
                if (n == -1)
                {
                        perror("read() failed");
                        return -2;
                }
                if (n == 0)
                {
                        // EOF received, that's OK
                        return i;
                }

                // NUL terminate the buffer
                buf[i + 1] = 0;

                // Check for end of line character
                if (buf[i] == '\n') {
                        buf[i] = 0;     // Remove ending \n
                        return i;
                }
                i++;
        }
}
```